# Preimage of quotient map

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $\phi: \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{9Z}$ be the quotient map defined by $\phi(n) = n + 9\mathbb{Z}$. Then we know $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}_9) = 3\mathbb{Z}$ by the radical of $\mathbb{9Z}.$

Now I don't understand how we can obtain the same answer from the perspective of the preimage of $\phi$.  Since the niradical is $\{\bar{0}, \bar{3}, \bar{6} \} = \{a + 9\mathbb{Z} : a \in H \}$. It suffices to ask all $H \subset \mathbb{Z}$ such that $9\mathbb{Z} \subset H$ which is just $H = 3\mathbb{Z}$. But doesn't $\phi(3\mathbb{Z}) = \{3n + 9\mathbb{Z}\}$? That's more than 3 elements right? And don't I actually get a different answer if I write

$\phi^{-1}( \{\bar{0}, \bar{3}, \bar{6} \}) = \phi^{-1}(\{ 0\}) \cup \phi^{-1}(\{ 3\}) \cup \phi^{-1}(\{ 6\}) = 9\mathbb{Z} \cup 3\mathbb{Z} \cup 6\mathbb{Z} = 3\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: I don't understand your second sentence.  $\phi$ is surjective, so $\phi^{-1}(\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}) = \mathbb{Z}$.  The radical of $9 \mathbb{Z}$ certainly is $3 \mathbb{Z}$, but I don't see how that's related to $\phi$.  It's also not clear to me what your definition of $H$ is.  Anyway, could you write out the problem statement clearly?

Comment: @Quasicoherent trying to find $\phi^{-1}( \{\bar{0}, \bar{3}, \bar{6} \}) $ under the quotient mapping. $H$ is the ideal $9\mathbb{Z} \subset H \subset \mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Okay, so you're trying to compute $\phi^{-1}(3\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})$.  $\phi^{-1}(3\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}) = 3\mathbb{Z}$ by the [Lattice Isomorphism Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correspondence_theorem_(group_theory)).  You can also prove this directly: if $a \in \phi^{-1}(3\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z})$, then $a + 9\mathbb{Z} = 3b + 9\mathbb{Z}$ for some $b \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $a - 3b \in 9\mathbb{Z}$, so $a - 3b = 9c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{Z}$.  Then $a = 3b + 9c = 3(b + 3c) \in 3 \mathbb{Z}$.  The reverse inclusion is immediate.